# how can spark streaming rerun the failed batch job

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

my question is that.
I use spark-streaming  read data from kafka with directSteam Api,process rdd then update zookeeper offset manually.
data from kafka will read and insert into hive table.
now I meet a question.
sometime the hive-meta store process exit for some reason.(now the hive-metastore is single)
some batch job will fail for that reason and the spark streaming job won't exit just log some warning.
then when I restart the hive metastore process, the program go on and the new batch job will succeed.
but I find that the failed batch read data from kafka is missing.
I see the meta data from the job detail.
image that one batch job read 20 offset from kafka.
the batch1 job read offset 1 20,
the batch2 job read offset 21 40
if batch1 job fail ,the batch2 succeed, the failed1 job 's data will missied.
how can I do this?
how can I rerun the failed batch job?